# is there a clean way of getting field name in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a method to copy over fields from one object to another

```
        public static T CopyEntity<T>(this T source, T other)
        {
            if (source.GetType() != other.GetType()) return default(T);
            var fields = source.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper().CompareTo("ID") != 0).ToList();

           

            foreach (var field in fields) 
            {
                field.SetValue(source,field.GetValue(other));
            }
            return source;
        }
```

there is the part where I filter out the id field because I would never want to copy that over.
What I want is to add optional parameters to filter other fields I may want to add on the fly, I know I could use something like

```
obj.CopyEntity<OBJ>(other,nameof(obj.foo));
```

is there a way to do it simply like

```
obj.CopyEntity<OBJ>(other,obj.foo);
```

and parse the field name in the method so I dont have to add nameof for every thing I
want the function to ignore?

Comment: If you don't want to write this code yourself, consider looking up the AutoMapper library.

Comment: In C# 10 you could use the `CallerArgumentExpression` attribute but that is overkill, you could also use an `Expression<Func<>>` parameter, but I don't see how that improves on `nameof` unless you might be dealing with nested fields.

Comment: PS probably shouldn't say fields (or name a variable `fields`) when you are dealing with properties.

Comment: can you do on the fly mappings like this in automapper?

Comment: its for entity framework I guess I always thought automapper gave a new object and with this I can keep the old object but if automapper does it that may be a better option

Comment: You could also use create a new anonymous type on the fly (`new { obj.foo, obj.foo2 }`) and use Reflection, but again probably overkill.